# How to remove the worm like underline in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using VS code for quite a while. Recently there are underline for almost each line of code in the JS project even though the code runs fine.

[image]

How to remove those false underlines?

Comment: Can you show us the error message ? I think it will help ;)

Comment: what is the language setting for this file (status bar lower right) Most likely it is wrong

Comment: `r0ulito`, here is the error message I found after replacing with single quote :   Replace `··········url:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg',␍` with `······url:·'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg',`eslintprettier/prettier

Comment: `rioV8`, it is javascript. The app is react native.

Comment: All wormlike underline disappear after disabling ESlint.